# Unicode Decode Error installing Senticnet using pip

Tags: python, unicode, pip

Trace:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: /home/geancarlo/Github/trolls_clasificator/venv/bin/python3.6 -c
'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
'"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wftowpu8/senticnet/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wftowpu8/senticnet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
            cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wftowpu8/senticnet/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-wftowpu8/senticnet/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
        license=open('LICENSE').read(),
        File "/usr/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for
full command output.
```

I'm trying to install [Senticnet](https://github.com/yurimalheiros/senticnetapi) with `pip` using a venv of Python 3. Some help? :(

Comment: The issue is a copyright sign in `LICENSE`. Maybe senticnet doesn't support Python 3. Did you try 2.7?

Comment: Installs fine for me with Python 3.7.3, pip 19.0.3 on OS X. What's your system? Do you have the latest pip? https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/761 seems relevant, so maybe `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` will help you.

Comment: pip 19.2.1 from /home/geancarlo/Github/trolls_clasificator/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6) @Nickolay

Comment: Where I should do the `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` ?

Comment: It works! @Nickolay, write it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> File "/tmp/pip-install-wftowpu8/senticnet/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
>    license=open('LICENSE').read(),
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
>    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

Character 12 of [senticnet's LICENSE](https://github.com/yurimalheiros/senticnetapi/blob/d7694d0b7d89767d8ce2d14e0c10d4600d16d447/LICENSE#L1) is indeed non-ascii: ©; but it installs fine for me.

The problematic code, `open('LICENSE').read()`, as noted in [pip's bug report](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/761), uses encoding derived from the system settings, which is ASCII on your machine.

On *nix running `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` before `pip install` should fix this.

Comment: It appears that this is fixed in python 3.7 via [PEP 538](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0538/)!